# How to draw a tetrahedron with angle marked?

Tags: diagrams

How to draw a tetrahedron with this point of view and with specific angle marked?

[image]

Thank you

I just find a sample code but I have no idea how to edit it.

```
\psset{viewpoint=40 10 10 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,Decran=30}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2,-2)(3,3)
\psSolid[object=tetrahedron,r=3,action=draw*,name=T,num=1 2 3]% without 0
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=T 0,text=Top,pos=uc]% Point T0 (top)
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: I have found some samples but I have no idea how to edit it.

Comment: \psset{viewpoint=40 10 10 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,Decran=30}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2,-2)(3,3)
\psSolid[object=tetrahedron,r=3,action=draw*,name=T,num=1 2 3]% without 0
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=T 0,text=Top,pos=uc]% Point T0 (top)
\end{pspicture}

Comment: Add as an edit to you question. Don't comment a lot of code like that.

Comment: Are you new to LaTeX or, more specifically, to packages to draw in LaTeX like TikZ, pgfplots, PSTricks, etc. ?

Comment: I am new to use LaTeX to draw graphics

Comment: Ok, then I think we could exclude those type of answers. Have you ever tried software that are able to generate tikz graphics or vectorial graphics?

Comment: You could use something like [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) or [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) and then export to tikz/eps/whatever.

Comment: I have tried geogebra before but it can only create 2D figures as I know? So gnuplot can create 3D figures like my picture in the qusetion?

Comment: You can with both.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446308/78282) will show you how to draw a tetrahedron with angles in TikZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your drawing in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), which you might like to learn.

[image]

Here's a `lualatex` program to create that as a standalone graphic.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    z0 = origin;
    z1 = 200 right rotated -20;
    z2 = 240 right rotated 10;
    z3 = 210 right rotated 60;

    path a[];
    a1 = .85[z1,z3] {dir  20} .. .83[z2,z3];
    a2 = .90[z2,z3] {dir 210} .. .90[z0,z3];
    a3 = .86[z0,z3] {dir -30} .. .88[z1,z3];

    draw a1 withcolor 3/4 blue;
    fill a2 -- z3 -- cycle withcolor .9[blue, white];
    draw a2 withcolor .7[blue, white];
    draw a3 withcolor 3/4 blue;

    draw z0--z2 dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
    draw z0--z1--z2--z3--cycle;
    draw z1--z3;

    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4 blue);
    label.lrt(textext("$\alpha$") rotated 40, point 1/2 of a1);
    label.lft("$\beta$", z3 shifted 20 left); 
    interim ahangle := 20;
    drawarrow z3 shifted 20 left {right}..z3 shifted -(4,5);
    label.bot("$\gamma$", point 1/2 of a3);

    drawoptions();

    label.llft("$A$", z0);
    label.lrt("$B$", z1);
    label.rt("$C$", z2);
    label.top("$V$", z3);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Note that there's no native 3D support in MP.  If you want to do lots of 3D work, then [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) is probably the best of the TeX-friendly tools.  But there are 3D libraries for [PSTricks](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot?lang=en) and for [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/) if you are keen to try them.  There are even also 3D libraries for Metapost ([like this one](http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~phan/m3Dplain.html)) but none of them is very easy to use.